# ThreeJs Texture wont appear

Tags: javascript, textures

I want to add a texture in ThreeJs to a box.
I dont see what I do wrong, in chrome and internet exp it dont work.

```
<script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>
    //Scene aanmaken
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //Camera 
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); 
    //Render instellen
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
    //Camera positie
    camera.position.z = 30; 
    camera.position.y = 10;
    //Orbit control aanroepen, voor rond te kijken in de scene
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


    var tafelGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,1,40);
    //Texture       
    var tableMaterials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "laken.jpg" ),side: THREE.DoubleSide} );

    var tafel = new THREE.Mesh(tafelGeometry,tableMaterials);
    scene.add(tafel);


    function render()
    {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    controls.update();
    }
    render();
```

I hope someone can help me. 
Kind Regards Patrick

Comment: I tried your code when served from a webserver and it works fine. The texture loads and looks ok, so I suspect as suggested above it may be a cross origin issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome prevents from loading the textures for security reasons. 
Try to open chrome (in Windows) with:

```
.\chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

(but don't visit other sites with that)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with loading textures. Be sure textures are loaded perfectly and you didn't got the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:/Desktop/Three.js/abc.jpg. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

If you got the above problem check using some web-editor (i.e. visual studio) by making Website.